Starfield CA not recoggnised by requests package
import requests
import time
response = requests.get('https://aviastacjapaliw.pl/stacje/avia-protasy/', verify=False)
print(response)
print(response.text)
time.sleep(1)
response = requests.get('https://aviastacjapaliw.pl/stacje/avia-protasy/')

second query fails with requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='aviastacjapaliw.pl', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /stacje/avia-protasy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1007)')))
openssl s_client -connect aviastacjapaliw.pl:443 -showcerts lists
depth=0 CN = aviapolska.pl
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = aviapolska.pl
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1

at the same time Firefox happily opens https://aviastacjapaliw.pl/stacje/avia-protasy/ and shows Starfield CA as root.
Where is the problem? Is it requests package bug to not recognise this CA?

In short: broken server configuration, missing intermediate certificates - see https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=aviapolska.pl. Browser can work around this broken setup, most other clients not.

@SteffenUllrich thanks, this resulted in https://codeberg.org/matkoniecz/list_how_openstreetmap_can_be_improved_with_alltheplaces_data/commit/0bbf837cd13a1a8b833314d3700fb9df61962067 (let me know if you prefer to not be quoted or if you prefer your user name to not be mentioned or if I should change anything else)
